# Using the properties of a continuous function to prove the following :

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be a continuous function. Also let $$A=\{ all \ x,y \ such \ that \ f(x,y)≥0\}\\ B =\{ all \ x,y \ such \ that \ f(x,y)=0\}$$

Show that $\operatorname{boundary}(A) \subset B$.

So isn't $\operatorname{boundary}(A)= B$,  I couldn't get why it would be a subset of $B$. Can you give a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate the following function on $[0, \infty)$ about the $y$ axis:
$g(x) = 1-x$ on $0 \leq x \leq 1$, and $g(x) = 0$ on $x > 1$.

Then $A$ is just $\mathbb{R}^2$, while $B$ is precisely $\{ (x, y) : x > 1 \}$.

The boundary of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is empty.

Comment: (+1) Or just take $f(x, y) = 0$ for all $(x, y)$. ;)